# dynamic creation of divs from a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im trying to achieve the following.

I have divs that are being created using json generayed from fields in a database, for the id of the div im using the id field passed through the json, this essentially creates a button. A the time of creating that div i have created another div that is populated by the message field contents passed in the json, what I would like to do is in creation of the second 'message div' hide it, then assign a onclick function to the first dynamically created div that would show the 'message div' when the first div is clicked.
I have looked at how to do this by dynamically creating css to do this but all the tuts i have read have been insufficient for my needs.

The following is the jquery im presently creating

```
$(document).ready(function() {//READY FUNC   

        $.getJSON("http://**************/**********/includes/messageRetrieve.php",function(data)  {//JSON

           $.each(data, function(key, val) {//iterate each data
               var id = val.id;
               var messageId = val.messageId;
               var messageSubject = val.messageSubject;
               var messageContent = val.messageDetail;

             $('#serverData').append('<div id="' + key + '" class="messageAlert">' + messageSubject + '</div>');
             $('#serverData').append('<div id="' + key + '" class="messageContent">' + messageContent + '</div>');


                        });//iterate each data

            });//JSON       

});//READY FUNC
</script>
```

Any help achieving this would be most helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly, your loop after the AJAX call should be :

```
var id = val.id;
var messageId = val.messageId;
var messageSubject = val.messageSubject;
var messageContent = val.messageDetail;
var container = $('#serverData');

var alert = $('<div id="' + key + '-alert" class="messageAlert">' + messageSubject + '</div>');
var content = $('<div id="' + key + '-content" class="messageContent">' + messageContent + '</div>');

alert.click(function() { content.toggle(); });
alert.appendTo(container);
content.hide().appendTo(container);
```

This way, the alert is appended to your `serverData` container and already bound to click and to the content that goes with it. Your content div is appended hidden (the `hide()` call) and the alert div will toggle it.

Also, in your original code you are creating two `div` with the same `id` (Your `key` variable) and two elements shouldn't have the same id, so I changed it to `key+'-alert'` and `key+'-content'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS to initially hide the `messageContent` fields:

```
.messageContent {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can use this jQuery to display the message:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serverData").on("click", ".messageAlert", function() {
        $(this).next(".messageContent").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: as all the created divs use the same class, wouldnt this way try to show all the message divs using this class. I had thought about using the css none on the message content div this way but as explained thought it would be probmatic

Comment: `$(this)` means just the DIV that was clicked on, and `$(this).next()` means the DIV right after it.